# Adding Custom Border to Sprite with perspective

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

**How to add border on an irregular polygon in flash with perspective?**

I have a Movieclip which let the user draw a surface and then apply a bitmap to fill in. I want the clip should be applied as a floor tile and then apply a custom border to the sprite which also has the same perspective as the floor?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try adding a really thin, dense GlowFilter.

Comment: I can share what i have achieved so far using drawtriangles API. But i guess i am still not up to mark to understand the process. Do you have any experience with the API @MartyWallace